# Log4j is already not configured via logback.groovy file in Grails 3.2.8

Tags: grails, logging, log4j

As we know by default logging in Grails 3.0 is handled by the Logback logging framework and can be configured with the **grails-app/conf/logback.groovy** file. The good part of this was that the configuration inside this file was applicable for the Logback and Log4j implementations (tested successfully in Grails 3.1.2). After we migrated to use Grails 3.2.8 from Grails 3.1.2 (as I said before), it seems that the configuration inside the logback.groovy file is not used by the Log4j and it should be configured in other way - at runtime.

I made a deep research in this to ensure that this is really the way it is configured now and it seems that if I am using the default Log4j logging:

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("name").info("TEST");
```

is not working at all. To make the information populated into the output log file, I should use the default SLF4J API:

```
org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger("name").info("TEST");
```

The problem here is because that we have a lot of places in the code where the logging is implemented using Log4j approach and now - nothing is written in the log file.

So I have two questions here. The first one - is this the exact way how Grails implemented this behavior (as nothing is mentioned in the official documentation - [Grails 3.2.8 Documentation](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/conf.html#logging)). The second one - is the XML or RUNTIME configurations are the best way to configure the Log4j, so use it as before. If yes - the bad thing here is that we should maintain two same configurations at a time. Is there any other way to configure the Log4j to use the same configuration as the Grails Logger.

P.S. There is no need to publish any code, as all are just default configurations.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
appender('STDOUT', ConsoleAppender) {
    encoder(PatternLayoutEncoder) {
        charset = Charset.forName('UTF-8')
    }
}

root(ERROR, ['STDOUT'])
logger("<package_name>", DEBUG)

List artifacts = ["conf", "controllers", "domain", "init"]
artifacts.each { artifact ->
    logger("grails.app.${artifact}.<package_name>", DEBUG)
}
```

After writing this, you can add logger for debugging in any artifacts mentioned above like:

```
log.debug "Any Message"
```

For more setting you can read here: https://logback.qos.ch/manual/groovy.html

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous post, using the default configuration (as you wrote here) makes the logging in Controllers and Services easier just by writing "log.debug "Any Message"". This is possible because in these files, the default logger is statically imported. This way the message will be written in the log file. The problem here is not with the default Grails logger, but with the Log4j configuration. In the previous Grails version that we used - 3.1.2, the configuration of both implementations - Logback and Log4j, was made with the logback.groovy file, but now only the Logback uses it.